# Scraping data with simple_html_dom class in PHP

Tags: php, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from the results on a search from [this website](http://www.birthdatabase.com/)

I have been told that the best way to do this is to use the simple_html_dom class from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
The result page is very busy and I am having trouble refining my scraped data.

I get the page content with:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.birthdatabase.com/cgi-bin/query.pl?textfield=' . $first . '&textfield2=' . $last . '&age=&affid=');
```

The code I was kindly given is:

```
$n = 0;
foreach($html->find('table tbody tr td div font b table tbody') as $element) {
    @$row[$n]['tr']  = $element->find('tr')->text;
    $n++;
}

// output your data
print_r($row);
```

Is this DOM navigation correct? Is there a better way to get the scraped data?

Thanks

Comment: They have advanced selectors. See there online documination. It is well documinated

Comment: I am quite the noob. Can you please help me refine the scrape?

Comment: You have to show your html to exmine by me

Comment: Here is an example of the HTML. http://www.birthdatabase.com/cgi-bin/query.pl?textfield=richard&textfield2=chun&age=&affid='

Answer (score 2):

you have killed my time. try if it is what you wanted: `:)`

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.birthdatabase.com/cgi-bin/query.pl?textfield=richard&textfield2=chun');
$people = array();
$cell = $html->find('table',2)->find('table',0)->find('tr');
$total = count($cell);
$i = -1;
foreach($cell as $element){
    if($i == -1) { $i++; continue; }
    if($i == $total-2) break;
    $people[$i]['f_name'] = $element->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $people[$i]['l_name'] = $element->find('td',2)->plaintext;
    $people[$i]['b_day'] = $element->find('td',3)->plaintext;
    $people[$i]['city'] = $element->find('td',4)->plaintext;
    $people[$i]['state'] = $element->find('td',5)->plaintext;
    $i++;

}

var_dump($people);

?>
```

Comment: Isn't it what you expected?